# blackberry AudioFormatControl

Tags: blackberry

when i record voice on os 5 ,i want to get AudioFormatControl  to format quality , i wrote code

like this ,

```
        player = Manager.createPlayer(encoding);
        player.realize();
        recordControl = (RecordControl) player.getControl(controlType);
        AudioFormatControl format = (AudioFormatControl) player
            .getControl("AudioFormatControl");
        format.setFormat("audio/amr");
        format.setParameter(FormatControl.PARAM_VERSION_TYPE,
                "MPEG1_layer_3");
        format.setParameter(FormatControl.PARAM_BITRATE, kbps);
        player.addPlayerListener(recordListener);
```

but format is null ,please help me , how to get AudioFormatControl in blackberry

Comment: I think this will helpful to you - http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/record-and-save-audio-file-in-sd-card.html